# JavaScript inner lambda function without var, let or const

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lambda

In the following React-Application, I am using a JS-Feature to declare a function within a function and call it on a certain event:

```js
export default function App() {
  OnClick = (input) => { //Why is no var/let needed
    //do something...
  }

  return (<button onClick={this.OnClick}/>); //and it is called like this
}
```

My resulting questions are:

- How is the "feature"/"notation" called? - it seems weird not to use var/let/const
- In which ES-Version was it introduced?
- Does it only work with Lambda-Functions?

Comment: It's called an "implicit global variable declaration" and you should not use it. It has nothing to do with `=>` functions; it's an assignment to an undeclared symbol.

Comment: If you put `"use strict";` at the very top of the module, that line would be an error.

Comment: *"and it is called like this"* Only if A) `App` is called as a function, not as a constructor, and B) You're in loose mode so `this` is the global object (`window` on browsers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How is the "feature" called? - it seems weard not to use var/let/const

I call it [*The Horror of Implciit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). `OnClick` gets created as a **global** variable, not a local one. I don't think it has an official name. A less opinionated one might be "implicit global variable creation." :-)

> In wich ES-Version was it introduced?

Before ECMAScript version 1. I think it was in the very first version of JavaScript ever in 1995.

> Does it only work with Lambda-Functions?

No, you can do this with any value. `OnClick = 42` would also "work."

**But don't**. Again, it creates a global, not a local. Instead, declare your variables.

Use `const` for your example (or `let` if you prefer). I also recommend using JavaScript modules ("ESM" or "ECMAScript" modules), because code in modules is in strict mode and assigning to an undeclared identifier is the error it always should have been in strict mode. If you don't want to use JavaScript modules, add `"use strict";` to the top of your files to put them in strict mode.

Here's a demonstration of the fact it creates a global:

```js
function example(value) {
    OnClick = () => {
        console.log(value);
    };
}

example(42);
OnClick(); // Logs 42
console.log(typeof window.OnClick); // "function"
```